# IO Exception was Unhandled in Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, windows-services

I have made a very basic windows service which contains a function to create text file in local drive of the system and the text file is being created successfully but when i am trying to write a string in the text file created it is giving following error..

```
the process can not access the file because it is used by another process.
```

And here is my windows service code ...

```
public void createtextfile() {
        System.IO.File.Create(@"D:\vikas.txt");
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        createtextfile();
        string conn = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=ipaddress;UID=myUserName;Pwd=myPassword;pooling=false";
        string Query = "Select * from ipaddress";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn);
        MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
           String ip=dr["ip"].ToString();

           System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\vikas.txt", ip);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to resolve the issue ..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.Create()` does **not just create** the file but it **opens** it and returns a valid handle (in the form of `Stream`, it'll be closed when GC will collect that object). To create an empty text file you may simply replace this:

```
System.IO.File.Create(@"D:\vikas.txt");
```

With this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\vikas.txt", "");
```

Moreover please note that you're writing data in a loop and each call to `File.WriteAllText()` will overwrite existing file. To **append text to existing file** (created empty in `createtextfile()`) change this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\vikas.txt", ip);
```

To this:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"D:\vikas.txt", ip);
```

Finally I would suggest to keep disposable objects in an `using` section (so, for example, I/O will fail you won't keep a DB connection open until GC will collect it):

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn))
using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(Query, con))
{
    // Code here
}
```